# array.sort compareFunction

Tags: arrays, sorting

```
 function function1() { 
 let array1 = ['3', '5', '10', '1', '4'];
 array1.sort(function (x, y) {
    return 1;
 });
 alert(array1);
 }
 function1();
```

The output shows array1 stays the same after sorting.
The output shows array1 is reversed when the returned value is changed to -1.

```
 array1.sort(compareFunction)
 Any compareFunction follows the syntax:

 function (x, y){
 /*
 body of code
 return a value 
 */
 }
```

The compareFunction should return a value. This returned value is used to sort the array.

If the returned value is negative, x is sorted before y.
If the returned value is positive, y is sorted before x.
If the returned value == 0, x and y remain unchanged.

If the returned value is positive,
y is sorted before x. Then why array1 remains unchanged?

I tried "return 1", "return 0", "return -1".

Comment: Your predicate just blindly returns `1`.  The sort calls your predicate to compare items.  If you just blindly return an answer without actually comparing the items then you risk describing your data as unsortable.  Sort asks: does A come after B? you: Yes!  Sort asks: does B come after A?  you: Yes!  Sort:  O_o??

Comment: Consider adding a language tag to the question.

Comment: Your input:  `['3', '5', '10', '1', '4']`.   My warning:  comparing numbers as strings is confusion waiting to happen. e.g.: the string `'10'` will sort lexicographically **before** the string `'5'`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not surprising that the array remains unchanged based on your answers to the questions the sorting algorithm asked of you to compare the items.  Here are the questions it asked and how you answered:

```js
function function1() { 
 let array1 = ['3', '5', '10', '1', '4'];
 array1.sort(function (x, y) {
    console.log(`I think ${x} comes after ${y}`);
    return 1;
 });
 console.log(array1);
 }
 function1();
```

output:

```
I think 5 comes after 3
I think 10 comes after 5
I think 1 comes after 10
I think 4 comes after 1
```

Cool, so it ordered the items as:

```
[ "3", "5", "10", "1", "4" ]
```

...which is unchanged from the input.

Compare the reverse order:

```js
function function1() { 
 let array1 = ['3', '5', '10', '1', '4'];
 array1.sort(function (x, y) {
    console.log(`I think ${x} comes before ${y}`);
    return -1;
 });
 console.log(array1);
 }
 function1();
```

Output:

```
I think 5 comes before 3
I think 10 comes before 5
I think 1 comes before 10
I think 4 comes before 1
```

As you wish, the "sorted" order is therefore:

```
[ "4", "1", "10", "5", "3" ]
```

...which is the input array in reverse order.

#### A typical compare function

Typically you want the predicate to actually compare the items.  A typical, (but perhaps surprising) way to do this is to use the expression `x - y` to compare them, which will put the strings in numeric order.  Since you can't subtract strings, the type conversion rules say that the operands will be converted to numbers first.

```js
function describe(v) {
   if (v < 0) return 'comes before';
   if (v > 0) return 'comes after';
   return 'is the same as';
}
function function1() { 
 let array1 = ['3', '5', '10', '1', '4'];
 array1.sort(function (x, y) {
    console.log(`I think ${x} ${describe(x - y)} ${y}`);
    return x - y;
 });
 console.log(array1);
 }
 function1();
```

Output:

```
I think 5 comes after 3
I think 10 comes after 5
I think 1 comes before 10
I think 1 comes before 5
I think 1 comes before 3
I think 4 comes before 5
I think 4 comes after 3
```

Therefore these things should be placed in the order:

```
[ "1", "3", "4", "5", "10" ]
```

Comment: How the compare function works? Take the last example. "I think 5 comes after 3 I think 10 comes after 5". It seems x and y were reversed. x should be 3 and y should be 5. How were the next pair of (x, y) selected? From the Internet, the compare function takes the value at index 0 as x and every other value one by one as y . Sorting is then done based on its return value. I do not see how each pair of (x, y) were selected.

Comment: @jerseypizza the specific algorithm used by Array.sort is not explicitly defined in the ECMAScript specification.  But as an example, [if you are using Chrome](https://v8.dev/blog/array-sort#history), then it is selecting items to compare based on the Quicksort algorithm with an Insertion Sort fall-back for shorter arrays < 10 items.  In short, it is comparing and rearranging the items to efficiently get the list sorted by minimizing the number of comparisons, and swaps needed to put the items in sorted order.  Feel free to study sorting algorithms online.